# Flask Flask_mysqldb (MySQL) raise AssertionError in app route method

Tags: python, mysql, flask

AssertionError
AssertionError: A setup function was called after the first request was handled. This usually indicates a bug in the application where a module was not imported and decorators or other functionality was called too late. To fix this make sure to import all your view modules, database models and everything related at a central place before the application starts serving requests.
Traceback (most recent call last) 
File "C:\Users\joaog\Documents\tryflask\app.py", line 240, in resposta_insert 
if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():

try:

```
mysql = MySQL(app)

cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
```

except Error as e:

```
print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)

print()
```

finally:

```
mysql = MySQL(app)

cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
```

CODE OF THE METHOD:

```
@app.route('/respostas/<int:pergunta_id>/<int:aluno_id>',  methods=["POST"])
def resposta_insert(pergunta_id, aluno_id):
    form = RespostaForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        # VERIFICA SE OS FORMULARIOS ESTAO BEM FEITOS
        resposta_sql = request.form["resposta_sql"]
        # INSERE NA BASE DE DADOS A NOVA RESPOSTA
        try:
            mysql = MySQL(app)
            cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        except Error as e:
            print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
            print()
        finally:
            mysql = MySQL(app)
            cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

        query = "INSERT INTO resposta (pergunta_id, aluno_id, resposta_sql) VALUES (%s,%s,%s);"
        cur.execute(query, (pergunta_id, aluno_id, resposta_sql))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        # SELECIONA O ULTIMO INDEX INSERIDO
        cur.execute("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();")
        data_last_inserted_id = cur.fetchall()
        last_inserted_id = data_last_inserted_id[0][0]
        # PREPARA ESTRUTURA PARA COMPARACAO DE TABELAS VIA MYSQL AND DATASETS

        # PESQUISA O QUERY MYSQL DA PERGUNDA DO PROFESSOR
        query = "SELECT PERGUNTA_SQL,QUERY_ID FROM PERGUNTA WHERE PERGUNDA_ID = %s"
        cur.execute(query,(pergunta_id,))
        data = cur.fetchall()

        sqlquery = data[0][0]
        sqlquery.upper()

        # PESQUISA O QUERY MYSQL DA RESPOSTA DO ALUNO
        sqlqueryal = resposta_sql
        sqlqueryal.upper()

        #sqlparsed = sqlparse.parse(sqlquery)

        sqlquerykey = data[0][1]

        # print()
        import mysql.connector
        try:
            print("Cria a connexão!")
            print()
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                                database='jg_teste',
                                                user='root',
                                                password='user')

            if connection.is_connected():

                # ACRESCENTAR O ID
                def acrescentar_id(query, id_):
                    queryparsed = sqlparse.parse(query)
                    # print(queryparsed[0])
                    lista = list()
                    for each in queryparsed[0]:
                        if each.value == "SELECT":
                            lista.append(each.value)
                            lista.append(" ")
                            lista.append(id_+",")
                        else:
                            lista.append(each.value)
                    lista = ''.join(lista)
                    # print(lista)
                    return lista

                print("IMPRIME A DATA_FRAME_KEY")
                print(sqlquerykey)
                # ACRESCENTAR O ID A QUERY #
                ############################
                print()
                print("CHAVE:")
                print(sqlquerykey)
                print()
                print("SQL QUERYS")
                sqlqueryprof = acrescentar_id(sqlquery, sqlquerykey)
                print(sqlqueryprof)
                sqlqueryalun = acrescentar_id(sqlqueryal, sqlquerykey)
                print(sqlqueryalun)

                # EXECUTAR CADA UMA DAS QUERYS
                cursor_prof = connection.cursor()
                cursor_prof.execute(sqlqueryprof)
                records_prof = cursor_prof.fetchall()

                data_frame_prof = pandas.DataFrame(records_prof)
                # print(data_frame_prof)

                cursor_alun = connection.cursor()
                cursor_alun.execute(sqlqueryalun)
                records_query = cursor_alun.fetchall()

                data_frame_alun = pandas.DataFrame(records_prof)
                print()

                # COMPARACAO DOS DATA FRAMES
                data_prof = pandas.read_sql(sqlqueryprof, con=connection)
                data_alun = pandas.read_sql(sqlqueryalun, con=connection)

                # datacompy
                compare = datacompy.Compare(
                    data_prof,
                    data_alun,
                    join_columns=sqlquerykey)

                # IMPRIMIR RESULTADOS DA COMPARACAO ##
                ######################################
                print("#######################################################################################################")
                print("Colunas que intreceptaram", len(compare.intersect_columns()))
                print("Linhas que intreceptaram", compare.intersect_rows.shape[0])
                print()
                print("Linha unicas no DataFrame 1:", len(compare.df1_unq_rows))
                print("Linha unicas no DataFrame 2:", len(compare.df2_unq_rows))
                print()
                print("Colunas unicas de Dataframe 1 :", compare.df1_unq_columns())
                print("Colunas unicas de Dataframe 2 :", compare.df2_unq_columns())

                cursor_prof.rowcount

                numero_linhas_totais = len(compare.df1_unq_rows)
                numero_linhas_iguais = compare.intersect_rows.shape[0]
                colunas_totais = compare.df1_unq_columns()
                colunas_iguais = len(compare.intersect_columns())

                table_prof = extract_tables(sqlqueryprof)
                table_alun = extract_tables(sqlqueryalun)

                campos_totais = len(table_prof)
                campos_iguais = len(table_prof & table_alun)

                query = "INSERT INTO RESULTADO (numero_linhas_totais, numero_linhas_iguais, colunas_totais,colunas_iguais,campos_totais,campos_iguais, pergunta_pergunta_id) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);"
                cur.execute(query,(numero_linhas_totais,numero_linhas_iguais,colunas_totais,colunas_iguais,campos_totais,campos_iguais,pergunta_id))


                # print(data_frame_prof)
        except Error as e:
            print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
            print()
        finally:
            # closing database connection.
            if(connection.is_connected()):
                cursor_prof.close()
                cursor_alun.close()
                connection.close()
                print("MySQL connection is closed")


        # SELECIONA A RESPOSTA ANTERIORMENTE INSERIDA
        query = "SELECT RESPOSTA_SQL FROM RESPOSTA WHERE RESPOSTA_ID = %s;"
        cur.execute(query, (last_inserted_id,))
        data = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()
        js = json.dumps(data)
        resp = Response(js, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
        resp.headers['Links'] = 'http://127.0.0.1/respostas/'
        return resp
    elif request.method == 'POST' and not form.validate():
        resp = Response(status=400)
        resp.headers['Links'] = 'http://127.0.0.1/respostas/'
        return resp
```

Comment: Sorry for the editing i will change it...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was here:

```
    query = "INSERT INTO resposta (pergunta_id, aluno_id, resposta_sql) VALUES (%s,%s,%s);"
        cur.execute(query, (pergunta_id, aluno_id, resposta_sql))
        mysql.connection.commit()
```

The column names were wrong